# Best way to merge and unmerge objects without losing data

Tags: python, database, django, django-models, schema

Say I have two tables (I am using Django, but this question is mostly language agnostic):

```
Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

Event(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Users are allowed to create both events and organizations. There is the chance that two separate users create organization objects that are supposed to resemble the same real world organization. When someone notices this problem, they should be able to merge the two objects so there is only one organization.

The question I have is this: How do I merge these two organizations in order to ensure I can "unmerge" them if the user incorrectly merged them? Thus, the simple solution of deleting one of the Organization objects and pointing all Events to the other one is not an option. I am looking for very high level guidelines on best practices here.

A few possible solutions:

- Add another table that joins together organizations that have been "merged" and keep track of merges that way
- Add a foreign key field on Organization to point to an organization it was merged with
- Keep copies of all of the original objects as they existed before a merge, using something like [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/wiki/Deprecated-Low-Level-API)

Comment: not part of your world, but OWL and FOAF ontologies are exactly for this...  these are based on rule definitions with a declaration of equivalence between two objects that may later be revoked or disputed.  In the database world, this would be equivalent to adding another link table between the two orgs - easy enough to populate, but then you have query difficulties to ask the proper question.

Comment: Looks like OWL and FOAF probably won't work for what I'm doing, but thanks for bringing this up! It's fun to learn new things.

Comment: As for your comment about adding links between the different orgs, I agree that this is definitely a realistic approach, although slightly annoying in practice since queries will be more complex.

Comment: Yeah - i thought i'd throw out that wildcard for you, but not really practical to switch gears so entirely.  The queries will probably be more than slightly annoying- those would be tough questions and you would need to bake them in to almost everything you ask...

Comment: Agreed. The more I think about how I'd deal with querying over linked models, the more issues I find with it. I'm leaning towards a solution closer to django-reversion where I'd simply keep track of all the previous data and then figure out how to unmerge based on those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would go with a solution which uses something like `django-reversion`.  However, if you want to create something more robust and less dependent on 3rd party logic, add a `merged_into` field to Organization and `merged_from` field to Event:

```
Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    merged_into = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)

Event(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)  
    merged_from = models.ForeignKey(Organization null=True, blank=True)
```

On merge, you can choose update the events as well.  From now on, be sure to redirect all references of "merged_into" organizations into the new organization.

If you want to allow multiple merges (for example: A + B into C, A+C into D, E+F into G and D+G into H), you can create a new organization instance each time and merge both "parents" into it, copying the events instead of updating them.  This keeps the original events intact waiting for a rollback.  This also allows merging more than 2 organizations into a new one in one step.

Comment: I was leaning towards rolling my own thing similar to this, so I am glad to read your recommendation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be a diff-like interface. For each field, you provide all the possible values from the objects being merged. The person merging them chooses the appropriate value for each field. You'd probably only want to show fields on which a conflict was detected in this view.

After all conflicting fields have had a "good" value chosen for them. You create a new object, assign relationships from the old versions to that one, and delete the old versions.

If you're looking for some sort of automatic approach, I think you'd be hard pressed to find one, and even if you did, it would not really be a good idea. Any time you're merging anything you need a human in the middle. Even apps that sync contacts and such don't attempt to handle conflicts on their own.

Comment: hmm, I agree that making a good merge tool is very important, but this solution doesn't solve the problem of "unmerging" the data if something goes wrong. We lose information by deleting the old versions, and it is important for my app to have the ability to restore to the original state if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a key hack.

Organization will have usual id field, and an another 'aliases' field. 'aliases' field would be comma separated ids. In that field you'll track the organizations that may be pointing to the same in real world. Let's say there was a 2 organization named organization_1, organization_2 and id is 1, 2.

```
organization_1           organization_2
_id = 1                  _id = 2
aliases = '1, 2'         aliases = '2, 1'
```

If you want to query event's that is only belong to organization_1, you can do it. If you want to query all events of organization_1, organization_2, you check it if aliases field contains the key. Maybe separator should be not just ',' it should also surround aliases field a whole. Something like ',1,2,'. In this way we can be sure to check if it contains ',id,'